# Messaging notifications send flow error

Tags: notification, digital-engagement

I have a flow of sending message notifications by whatsapp
The flow has triggers to send a message based on changes in opportunity phases

I performed the complete configuration of the channels and the actions:

[image]

But when sending, 2 different error logs are returned to me for a single sending:

The first one with the message correctly filled in, but without the template, Origin ID and recipient's phone fields filled in
[image]

And another with the recipient's template and phone number filled in, but without the message and with the missing fields error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using recipient.phone number then you also need to include recipient record ID and reference it, otherwise it wont work.
the documantation is misleading